# Java Web App FutureTask Progress Bar

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, web-applications, progress-bar

I have a Java web application that performs a long running task via a struts action. I would like to display a progress bar for the task and would like to update the progress bar via AJAX which calls some action to get the current progress of the running thread.

What is the best practice for accomplishing this? If action A executes the FutureTask thread, how do I access this FutureTask object from another action to get its current progress? Is this even possible or is there a better approach to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the FutureTask or the Callable in the Session and then pull it out in the other action to check the progress.

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts. I'm thinking of taking it a step further and storing the object on server side cache. That way, the user can logout and log back in later to check the progress of the same running task.

Comment: Sounds good, just make sure whatever you are storing is serializable.