# Java Web Application : Monitoring Progress

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, progress-bar

Many times there are some long running processes called by http servlets in java web application. A typical example will be, converting 100 mp3 files to flak format (just a random example). The http connection will be alive but since the process will take long long time, we can build some progress bar to display on the web page (preferably uisng ajax) which indicates the progress of the task. What should be the design pattern for this? Say, Servlet's post method will invoke the actual long term process, and Servlet's get method will invoke the progress listener?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474080/java-web-app-futuretask-progress-bar) for one idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java EE I would recommend the following structure:

- a Servlet call (POST for example) will start the process
- the POST will use an `@Asynchronous` EJB call to process the heavy load, so that will start doing the long-taking process
- It will also pass a *progress holder object*, e.g. a POJO which is put into the context/session (a @Stateful EJB will also do)
- the POST returns, the background job continues
- The status check is carried out by Ajax HTTP calls, they use the same session as the starter
- the Ajax call gets the *progress holder object* from session/context/@Stateful, reads the status and returns
- the status is continuously updated by the background thread (the update should be synchronized unless you use only one attribute of boolean, char, int or float (max 32bit primitives))

Note that `@Asynchronous` is available since EJB 3.1.